# Need to fix infinite scroll

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Well the main infinite scroll is working correct. If I make infinite scroll ONLY for posts then it's working fine, if I make infinite scroll ONLY for random news( right sidebar) it's working fine. But if I make infinite scroll for both and in the single page, the posts starts to messing up like this:

[image: Ren content shuold be where the arrow points]

As you can see posts just appears after random posts ant then after those posts appears the last random posts.

This is the code of posts.

```
<div class="row">
            @foreach($posts as $post)
            @if($latest->id != $post->id)

             THIS IS WHERE SCROLL BEGINS

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6 scroll">
            <a href="/post/{{$post->slug}}/{{$post->id}}">
            <img class="img-responsive" style="width: 352px; height: 180px" src="{!! url($post->image) !!}" alt=""></a>
              <h3 class="post" style="font-size: 1.4em;">

              @foreach($post->category as $cat)
              <a style="color: red; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 13px" href="/categories/{{$cat->name}}">{{$cat->name}}</a>
              @endforeach

              <br><a class="post" href="/post/{{$post->slug}}/{{$post->id}}">{{strip_tags($post->title)}}</a></h3>
              <span style="color: #b8b8b8">Paskelbta {{$post->created_at}}</span>
              <br><br>
            </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
            @endif
            @endforeach


          </div><!--/row-->
           {!! $posts->render() !!}
        </div><!--/.col-xs-12.col-sm-9-->

         THIS IS WHERE I INCLUDE SIDEBAR
         @include('comp.sidebar')

       </div><!--/row-->

      <hr>


      INFINITE SCROLL CODE

        {!! Html::script('jscroll-master/jquery.jscroll.min.js') !!}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.scroll').jscroll({
        autoTrigger: true,
        nextSelector: '.pagination li.active + li a', 
        contentSelector: 'div.scroll',
        callback: function() {
            $('ul.pagination:visible:first').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is right sidebar code:

```
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" style="padding: 0px">
                <div class="portlet">
                    <div class="portlet-title">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i>
                            <span class="caption-subject text-uppercase"> Atsitiktiniai</span>
                            <span class="caption-helper">viskas po ranka</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                   THIS IS WHERE SCROLL BEGINS

                    <div class="scroll">
                    @foreach($randomPosts as $posts)
            <img class="popImage" src="{!! url($posts->image) !!}" />
            <p><a class="popTitle" href="/post/{{$posts->slug}}/{{$posts->id}}">{{$posts->title}}</a></p><br>                           

                    @endforeach
                        <div style="display: none">{!! $randomPosts->render() !!}</div>
                    </div>

                </div>          
        </div><!--/.sidebar-offcanvas-->


                INFINITE SCROLL CODE

        {!! Html::script('jscroll-master/jquery.jscroll.min.js') !!}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.scroll').jscroll({
        autoTrigger: true,
        nextSelector: '.pagination li.active + li a', 
        contentSelector: 'div.scroll',
        callback: function() {
            $('ul.pagination:visible:first').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using twitter-bootstrap?

Comment: Do you have it live? If so provide us a link, better to solve your issue.

Comment: @divy3993 I'm still on localhost...

Comment: Ok, Still am not getting your issue in question. It would be better if you create a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or make it somehow live. So that could be understood and solved easily. I know there is PHP, but still.

Comment: This is before scrolling - http://www.part.lt/img/38f2ba9393f4603350500307aa289d2b474.png
And this is after scroll - http://i.stack.imgur.com/SDWp7.png

Comment: I just can't make it in these three windows. Only problem is that the post that should apear in center they appears in the right sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

In your main body you have too many `</div>`'s I'm guessing this is your issue unless you've missed extra code from your page.